# Can we create plugin for shopify in php?

Tags: shopify

I am trying to develop app/plugin for shopify in PHP. Shopify is fully develped in Ruby on Rails. There are so many apps developed for shopify that are installable. I tried to search plugin for shopify that are made in PHP but couldn't find.
My question is that can we create installable app/plugin in PHP for shopify? If yes then it will support for shopify? Please clarify me.

Comment: You can create a service in php that will be consumed via API by a plugin. But that plugin has to be written in Ruby. But the service can be fully be creted in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

All your interaction with Shopify is via a RESTful API. You can create your App/Plugin in any language you want. It makes zero difference to Shopify, so long as you deal with the API correctly. .Net, Python, Ruby, PHP, Go, Javascript, take your pick.

There are a couple of open-source PHP example Apps floating around out there, suitable as a starting point for your copy&paste efforts. Working with Shopify API in PHP allows you to draw from PHP samples of connecting to any other common API out there, nothing special.